# Strange behavior when changing $*SCHEDULER after execution of external program

Tags: raku, rakudo

### Description

There is an example:

```raku
#!/bin/env raku
run 'raku', '-e', 'say "ok"';
exit 0;
my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new(max_threads => 128);
```

On linux output is:

```
ok
Unhandled exception in code scheduled on thread 4
No such method 'cue' for invocant of type 'Any'
```

On windows output is:

```
Unhandled exception in code scheduled on thread 4
No such method 'cue' for invocant of type 'Any'
  in method throw at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Exception.pm6 line 65
  in method schedule_thens at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Promise.pm6 line 167
  in method keep at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Promise.pm6 line 127
  in method keep at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Promise.pm6 line 83
  in block  at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Proc/Async.pm6 line 390
  in block  at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/ThreadPoolScheduler.pm6 line 263
  in method run-one at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/ThreadPoolScheduler.pm6 line 244
  in block  at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/ThreadPoolScheduler.pm6 line 308
  in sub THREAD-ENTRY at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Thread.pm6 line 69
```

Sometimes it prints `ok` before an error, sometimes after one, sometimes it doesn't print it. I didn't find a pattern of this.

### Questions

1. Is this a bug?
2. What does this error mean and why does it appear?
3. Why does this happen even after `exit 0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a default setting for `$*SCHEDULER`, because all of the async functionality depends on that.

By adding a `$*SCHEDULER` to that scope, you're overriding that, which I assume is your intent.

However, at the moment the `run` runs, it is **NOT** set yet: it is `Any`.  So the `run` tries to `cue` the action to execute the command, but there is no scheduler available to cue this on.

The fix?  Make sure the scheduler is set **before** executing `run`:

```
my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new(max_threads => 128);
run 'raku', '-e', 'say "ok"';
exit 0;
```

So to answer your questions:

1. No, it is a case of DIHWIDT
2. See above
3. That's a matter of timing, I guess, although it is a bit puzzling.  My guess would be is that the `cue` is for handling the result of `run`, not for the `run` itself.  So it starts executing, and after it has started, it finds out it can't actually cue the handler of the result of the `run`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

I've found that to really do what I want, I can just put the scheduler change to another scope. Actually, this is stated in the documentation, but not clear enough.